# Conditionals when initialising node.js scripts

Tags: node.js, shell

I have a node.js executable script which usually starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var ...
```

In order to use a command line argument `--use_strict` on the node.js binary, I'd need to change this to

```
#!/usr/bin/env node --use_strict
```

which could possibly screw up for other people.

Is there a way to check if --use_strict has been provided when calling the script and then pass it to the node executable?

something like

```
./myscript --use_strict
---
if --use_strict
  #!/usr/bin/env node --use_strict
else
  #!/usr/bin/env node
```

Comment: These aren't bash scripts. They are `node` scripts. And you can't actually guarantee that `#!/usr/bin/env node --use-strict` is even going to work. (Support for multiple arguments isn't guaranteed to be supported.) Is it not possible to set `--use-strict` in the script itself?

Comment: `#!` must be the first two characters of the script, you can't put them anywhere else without them being just a comment.  Why not do that `if` statement from a bash script?  You can run a `node` script in the same way as from the command-line.

Comment: @EtanReisner right. No, I can't set it in the script itself, it's a public npm module. Only solution I see at the moment is forking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/env node` will instruct the operating system to call the command after the `#!` ("shebang") on the file. If your script is in the file `your-node-script`, the OS basically runs this:

```
/usr/bin/env node your-node-script
```

The `env` command will search for the first argument in your environment and execute it with the remaining arguments. If your `node` executable is in `/usr/bin/node`, on your system it will call:

```
/usr/bin/node your-node-script
```

To solve your problem, you just write a wrapper script which does the same to call your node script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/env node --use-strict your-node-script "$@"
```

Or:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/node --use-strict your-node-script "$@"
```

(Which only works on systems where `node` acrually is in `/usr/bin`.

---

**Edit:** Parameters are now forwarded (thanks *Etan Reisner*).

Comment: The wrapper scripts here do not forward arguments to the node script. (That may or may not matter here but for generality's sake that should be included in the wrapper script.)